# NSSortDescriptor issue with sorting single and double digits number

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, sorting, nssortdescriptor

i sort my array by experience using this code

```
sortexp = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"Experience" ascending:YES];

arrData = [arrData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortexp]];

NSLog(@"%@",arrData);
[tblResponseData reloadData];     
NSLog(@"Experience");
```

but problem is that it's wrong count when compare single digits and double digits number.

example - `array = {10,3,11,35,6,7}` and after sort it will `array = {10,11,3,35,6,7}`

so how can i convert my single digit number in double digits using prefix `0` with number , my data is come from server so i can't change it so i do it's my side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically this is happening because you are sorting your numbers as string so it gives result in such a way (3 > 11 means it compares only first digit and if first digit same then compare next one) , you do not need to change the digits but sort them according to numbers not as string. For this you should use

```
sortexp = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"Experience" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

It will compare your numbers as number and string as string.

**EDIT:**

You can sort Using blocks as well.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {

 if ([[obj1 valueForKey:@"Experience"] integerValue] > [[obj2 valueForKey:@"Experience"] integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
 }

 if ([[obj1 valueForKey:@"Experience"] integerValue] < [[obj2 valueForKey:@"Experience"] integerValue]) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
 }
 return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: IMO sorting arrays using blocks is easier: - (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr; what do you think?

Comment: I use blocks when I have to do sorting considering multiple keys otherwise I use NSSortDescriptor. Using blocks it gives you much more freedom to do any complex comparison as well. I have edited my answer for sorting using blocks.